# How to find form with two input using XPATH or javascript

Tags: javascript, xpath

Is there any way. how to find form with two input using xpath?

```
//form//input
```

works for X inputs, not for two.

Or, is there any way, how to do this using javascript?

Example

```
html page
form
input login
input psw

form 
input finder
```

So, on my pseudo html page is two forms, one form contains TWO inputs and second form contains only one input. I want localize first form using xpath, because first form contains two input elements.

Somethink like this:

```
//form//*[local-name()='input' and @type='text'] (AND BUT NOT WORKING) [local-name()='input' and @type='password']
```

Comment: Can you please add some example of what you want to obtain?
Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @GiulioCaccin I added example.

Comment: @praeslai has the solution worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
//html/form[count(input)=2]
```